# Can't build ios app with 64bit Support

Tags: ios, linker-errors, undefined-symbol

I’m trying to build my ios app and I’m having an issue with adding 64 bit support. Basically I added the `arm64` to my valid architectures and set `build active architectures only` to `no` but I’m still getting the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKSearchPredicate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CatalogController.o
```

If I remove the `64bit` from my architecture and simply have `arm7` then I'm not having any issues. Any advice or pointers would be appreciated.

FYI I already unplugged my devices and also tried deleting the `DerivedData` folder.

Comment: How old is your Restkit library? This issue was apparently fixed in November 2013: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/commit/157f27a28

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to get an updated version of RestKit.  Get it here:
https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit

Looks like RK was updated in April of 2014 to support 64 bit (v0.23.1)